# android- remove black background from launcher icon api 26

Tags: android, android-studio, android-launcher, android-icons

I've a big problem with launcher icon in api 26

I've png with transparent background , But it gets black on transparent parts

this is the result :

[image]

it's not for the theme because other apps has no background

this is my manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

this is the code for api 26

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>
<foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
```

this is the ic_launcher_background file , it's an transparent image :

[image]

this is the ic_launcher_foreground file :

[image]

how can I solve this ? how can I get rid of the black background ?

Comment: looks like it is the launcher app, which adds black background. Try with a different launcher

Comment: Have you copied the image directly to drawable and then referenced it in your manifest?

Comment: is it happening for all the devices? some device has custom OS they customize app icon according to their own theme.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I need to use that launcher , it has no background

Comment: @ArnabKundu it's not from the os , as I said other apps has no background

Comment: @UmangBurman thanks for reply , No , I used image asset in android studio

Comment: @johnsmoth Okay, Try deleting this: `<background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>`